# display array of dates in the Angular DropDown Menu

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

In Angular I retrieve timestamp from a JsonFile then I want to display it in the dropdown menu, but I don't know how to get the variable from the ngOnInit() to pass it to the variables, which I use to feed the dropdown menu. I put the placeholder in the code below 'timestamp from ngOnInit()', this must be a string.

here is the `search.component.ts` file:

```
 times: Timestamp[] = [
    { value: 'timestamp from ngOnInit()', viewValue: 'timestamp from ngOnInit()' },

  ];

  this.Service.getContent().then(results => {

      this.data = results;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {

    Object.entries(this.data[i].x_data).map(([key, value]) => {
      //timestamp
      this.xvalue = this.data[i].timestamp
   
      //converted timestamp to date & time
      this.date = moment(this.data[i].timestamp).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss').toLocaleString();


      this.strTimestamp = String(this.xvalue)
      this.strDate = String(this.date)

      return {
        timestamp: this.strTimestamp,
        date: this.strDate,


      }

    });

      }

    })

  }
```

the html file:

```
<form>   
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Select timestamp <mat-icon>access_time</mat-icon></mat-label>
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let time of times" [value]="time.value">
          {{time.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <p> Selected timestamp: {{selectedValue}} </p>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your template, your component.ts should create a variable called
`this.times` which should be an array containing objects in the form of:
`{ value: ..., viewValue: ...}`.

Right now you're creating an array of objects `{timestamp: ..., date: ...}` and you're not assigning this to an instance variable in your component.

Comment: yes you are right, how to assign this, could you give me a solution how to solve this problem?

Comment: ``this.times = Object.entries...``

Comment: thanks for the good approaches. how to pass the objects value and viewValue in this Object.entries function()